# onEachfeatures not displaying content but [object Object]

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geodjango

**i have a the following geojson and want to display the persons details on eachFeature**

**Bellow is properties section of my Geojson Output**

```
"properties": {"lr": "26697/751", "Registrations": {"Tenure_type": "leasehold", "persons": [{"PersonID": 7475, "name1st": "benard", "name2st": "gramps", "telephone": "02857215"}, {"PersonID": 7512, "name1st": "Jackie", "name2st": "morgan", "telephone": "0248571264"}]}}}
```

**Here is my code**

```
<body>
<h1>Ownership</h1>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
     function our_Layers (map, options){
        var datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'owner' %}",{                
            onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){                    

                layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.Registrations.persons.toString(), 
                {permanent:true, direction: 'right'});

            }
        });
        datasets.addTo(map); 

     }
</script>
{% leaflet_map "Owners" callback="window.our_Layers" %}
</body>
```

Comment: Is feature.properties.Registrations.persons an Object?

Comment: Persons attributes are enclosed in [ ] from my geojson output given above is there way to display them on popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the JSON.stringify() function to parse your object:

```
layer.bindTooltip(JSON.stringify(feature.properties.Registrations.persons), 
    {permanent:true, direction: 'right'});
```

To see the difference between the JSON.stringify() and the .toString methods I created the following code-snippet:

```js
var persons = [
    { "PersonID": 7475, "name1st": "benard", "name2st": "gramps", "telephone": "02857215" },
    { "PersonID": 7512, "name1st": "Jackie", "name2st": "morgan", "telephone": "0248571264" }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(persons));
console.log(persons.toString());
```

For more infos view: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Comment: Thanks man it worked. Is there a way i can format the JSON.stringify out put. like removes some characters or colour.

Comment: You can just edit it like a normal string, therefore using the .replace() method to edit or remove some characters. e.g. If you want to remove all 'l' characters from 'Hello world' just use 'Hello world'.replace('l', ''). This would give you 'Heo word'. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp for more infos.